# Difference between Initial Catalog and Database keyword in connection string

Tags: ado.net

What is the main difference between `Initial Catalog` and `Database` Keyword in a connection string?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The only difference is the name.

These can be used interchangeably.

See the documentation of [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.initialcatalog.aspx), under remarks:

> This property corresponds to the **"Initial Catalog"** and **"database"** keys within the connection string.

(emphasis mine)