# Difference between InitialCatalog and Database Name

Tags: sql-server, ssis, connection-string, sql-server-data-tools

I'm amidst "parameterizing" a connection in my package and I'm confused: I'm trying to set the database name but there are two options: 1- InitCatalog Name and 2- Name:

Here is what my connection looks like: 
[image]

And my parameter options are (as mentioned 1- InitCatalog Name and 2- Name): 
[image] 
and
[image]

So my question is: which one do I choose? I've read about "InitCatalog" and it seems to be where you'd define the default database within a server. But that could be defined under the name as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As answered here: [Difference between Initial Catalog and Database keyword in connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238548/difference-between-initial-catalog-and-database-keyword-in-connection-string)

> The only difference is the name.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I actually looked at that question before posting. My situation seems to be different because I'm looking at two properties one being the name, other being InitCatalog. In that question, the Connection String contains a "database keyword", I have no such thing. My connection String is as follows: 
"Data Source=SS2012;Initial Catalog=OrderProcessingSystem;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"