# How to add a linked sql server using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to replace my hardcoded SQL queries with LINQ expressions.

Here's the (simplified) code I want to replace:

```
List<string> sqlCommands = new List<string>
{
     @"EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname='LocalDB', @physname=N'C:\dbfile.mdf'",
     @"EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='NotLocalDB'"
};

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True");
conn.Open();

foreach (string commandString in sqlCommands)
{
     var command = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn);
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

conn.Close();
```

I've replaced the `sp_attach_single_file_db` command with this LINQ statement:

```
DBDataContext localDB = new
       DBDataContext(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=LocalDB; Integrated Security=True");

localDB.CreateDatabase();
```

But I can't find an equivalent command for `sp_addlinkedserver`.

Is there a way I can create a linked server for `localDB` using LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connStringBuilder.DataSource = ".\SQLEXPRESS";
connStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
connStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = "LocalDB";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStringBuilder)
```

Comment: What does that have to do with adding a linked, non-local DB?

Answer (score -2):

Try **Initial Catalog** instead of **Database**

and

**Data Source** instead of **Server**

Comment: I feel like that doesn't really answer my question, nor is it helpful because they're synonymous. See a)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12238552/2374028 and b)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15025693/2374028