# Invoke-Sqlcmd does not allow -E switch?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` from PSModule `SQLServer`.

My command when using `SQLCMD.exe` would use the [`-E` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=go%2Cwindows&pivots=cs1-bash#-e) for a trusted connection. I have referenced the docs online at [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) and cannot find where the option for `-E` is mapped out to?

The specific error text I get is:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

My command I am using looks like this:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $serverDN 
              -Database $dbName -EncryptConnection 
              -Username $userID -Password $passwd -InputFile $sqlFilePath
```

When I run that as a command prompt, it works fine:

```
Start-Process -FilePath sqlcmd.exe -WorkindDirectory $sqlcmdrootpath 
              -ArgumentList "-E -S ${serverDN} -d ${dbName} -U ${userID} -P ${passwd} -i ${sqlFilePath}"
```

How do I transcribe the `-E` switch?

Comment: `Get-Help Invoke-SqlCmd -Detailed` would have answered this for you. Under `-Username` it says, _If Username and Password are not specified, this cmdlet attempts a Windows Authentication connection using the Windows account running the Windows PowerShell session. When possible, use Windows Authentication._

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Using the Windows Authentication is not available in this instance. The commands are being run on a remote server that has no user account locally cached, and the process is started requiring a specified account.

Comment: The `-E` switch controls user authentication. Your error message is SSL certificate related so perhaps you're looking for an alternative to the `-C` switch to trust the remote server's certificate instead?

Comment: Use can use the sqlcmd.exe documentation which may be better than the powershell documentation.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 7):

This issue is caused by an untrusted server certificate (which, incidentally, is the `-C` switch, not the `-E` switch.

One option is to use the [`-ConnectionString` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#example-9-gain-full-control-of-a-connection). This will allow you to set [`TrustServerCertificate=True`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.trustservercertificate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) on the connection string itself.

```
$ConnectionString = "Server=$serverDN;Database=$dbName;User Id=$userId;Password=$passwd;TrustServerCertificate=True"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $ConnectionString -InputFile $sqlFilePath
```

Comment: Will `Database` work here? Doesn't it need to be `Initial Catalog`?

Comment: They should be interchangeable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12238552/402706