# Local SQL Server database custom file location

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core Web App 6 template with Identity Framework creates a default connection string:

```
Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplication1_RazorPages_test-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

The database files are created in the `C:\Users\{MyUser}` folder. I want the database to be created in a different location, for e.g. `{Project}\DataBase`.

I tried to add `AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1_RazorPages_test-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502.mdf` as an explicit path, but that returns an exception:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Specified LocalDB instance name is invalid.).

I also tried `AttachDbFileName=C:\aspnet-WebApplication1_RazorPages_test-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502.mdf`, as well as few other locations. The current Windows user is Administrator, so there is no issue with permissions.

I noticed the original connection string uses `Database` instead of `Initial Catalog`. I have seen in the past.

How can I enforce a custom database file location, preferably within the VS project folder?

Comment: I would ask why you are attaching a database instead of adding it your sql instance.

Comment: Attaching database is probably the wrong direction. Anyway the core question remains the same, how to enforce custom files location.

Comment: Some info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150238/localdb-change-sql-server-default-location and perhaps adding this library could solve the problem programmatically https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb/wiki

Comment: And for _Database vs Initial Catalog_ see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238548/difference-between-initial-catalog-and-database-keyword-in-connection-string

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the default settings from the sql server.

Step 1. Right Click on Server and Select "Properties".

Step 2. in the "Server Properties" dialog box, navigate to "Database Settings" tab and data/log files location under "Database default locations" group. You can also change default backup location here.

Step 3. Click on "OK" to apply changes.

All new databases will be created to new location unless specified explicitly.

[image]

Comment: My ultimate goal is to enforce a custom database file location within the VS project folders. So each VS Project has its own corresponding localdb created by Entity Framework / Identity Framework within its structure.

Answer (score 0):

1 Step
Make mssql service local system account then restart

then add this connection string to the project

Data Source=./;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Bayram Eren\source\repos\WebApplication2\test.mdf;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True